# Weird points and lines appearing in custom JPanel when another component updates

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea, repaint

so I have been working on developing a GUI for an upcoming project,
and I have to admit that even after about 2 years of Java, I'm still not good at GUI design and programming.

First of all, here's a screenshot of the current version of the JFrame: [image]

I made a little custom JPanel that is going to display a graph later on,
for now it's just random. It's the thing in the lower right. Now if I just repainted that and did all my stuff, nothing would be wrong, but I have to update the JTextArea (which is included in a JScrollPane by the way), I every time set the caret to the very last position, so that it automatically scrolls down. And this causes, in my own custom JPanel, small dots and lines to appear and flicker, which I believe is caused by the JTextArea.
When the window has certain proportions, or if I don't update the caret position, this doesn't occur.

I have already tried a few things: Synchronizing everything related with the EDT, scheduling my repaints, etc. but nothings seems to help.

Has anyone ever come across a similar situation and knows how to fix it?
I could really use some help here.

Thanks in advance,
Tom S.

Comment: Nope, but I am willing to take a look if you post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org)

Comment: Be certain to honor the [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) property.

Comment: I figured it out. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I think is too hard to say something wise in conections with @camickr's [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/)